# cs231n lec 14 reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, cs231n

I'm studying CS231N, lecture 14, "Reinforcement Learning". In the lecture, the instructor mentioned the value function, which is shown in the picture:

[image: picture of value function]

I am wondering what is that bar between `rt` and `s0`? I thought it was something like conditional probability, but I'm not sure about it. Or is it just a division?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://math.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the conditional probability. It literally means the reward at time `t`, given state `s`, following policy `pi`.

Comment: what does s0 mean in that equation? is it mean that the summation start in the initial state? or current state?